# Finding order of four numbers provided three inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Find largest number from $A,B,C,D$:
>
> $$A+B <C+D \tag{1}$$
>
> $$B+D < A+C \tag{2}$$
>
> $$A+D< B+C \tag{3}$$

#### Attempt:

From adding (1) and (3) simplifying, and similarly with (2) and (3),  I find:

$$A<C \\ D<C$$

Adding all the three equation tells me that:

$$A+B+D <3C$$

Which doesn't seem to lead me anywhere.

Somewhere behind C on the number line  $A$ and $D$ are located without us knowing the order, and it's also unclear where $B$ is. It could be either to right or left of C.

## Why I think I am stuck

I am presuming some sort of proof by contradiction is required now to proceed further. Now, the problem I have is, what exactly do we assume to generate out the contradiction?

Suppose I take an order, and it's actually right, then working out on the inequalities won't actually lead me anywhere. So, I have to intentionally choose a wrong one, which I'd say, requires intuition of the answer... but I don't have any :(

Comment: You are already done. From your last inequality you also get $B<C$. So $C$ is the largest, and indeed this can happen: $(A,B,C,D)=(1,1,C,1)$ works for all $C\ge 2$. By the way, the picture isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addendum added to respond to the comment of Dietrich Burde.

---

Add inequalities  (1) and (3) together.
This implies that $~2A < 2C.$

Add inequalities (1) and (2) together.
This implies that $~2B < 2C.$

Add inequalities (2) and (3) together.
This implies that $~2D < 2C.$

---

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

Responding to the comment of Dietrich Burde:

> You have shown that, if such 4 numbers exist, C is the largest. But do they exist?

Good point. I totally overlooked the issue.

Satisfying example is $~(A,B,C,D) = (5,1,6,1).$

Comment: damn I made a calculation error when I added (1) and (2) then started making out the question to be much more complicated than it actually is

Comment: You have shown that, if such $4$ numbers exist, $C$ is the largest. But do they exist?

Comment: @DietrichBurde See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Obviously yes: given any reals $A, B, D$, the inequalities are true if $C$ is large enough.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Your conclusion may not be that obvious to the original poster.  So, from the original poster's perspective, it is a legitimate issue.